# How do I scrape controls on an Windows Forms application which doesn't have an handle?

Tags: c#

I have a Windows application. Where can I find the handle of the window?

I am unable to find the handle of the controls placed within that window. How can I scrape such controls? If it's a textbox or a button, I can automate it using the move position and send message. How does this work with a data grid/ table?

Comment: Use the System.Windows.Automation namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to the Win32 API for that.

Import EnumChildWindows like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool EnumChildWindows(Intptr parent, EnumWindowsProc enumProc, IntPtr lParam);

public delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);
```

And then call it from you main windows with this.Handle as the parent's windows handle. It will call the delegate for every child control in the form. This will show a messagebox for every control in the window:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, System.Text.StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

EnumChildWindows(this.Handle, (handle, b) => {
    int length = GetWindowTextLength(handle);
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(length + 1);
    GetWindowText(handle, sb, sb.Capacity);
    MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString()); return true;
}, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the response, But  this approach dint return the handle of the controls I was looking for .  in my case , I have the handle of the last child window ,  this window has various controls. I'm not able to access those controls. They are not visible even in spy++. is there any way to access such controls, that are placed inside a custom container/shell windows